# "load", "beforeunload" event listeners not working in Salesforce Data Cloud Web SDK

Tags: javascript, datacloud, interaction-studio

I'm trying to add an event listener inside listeners in PageConfig in Data Cloud Web SDK Sitemap to track the interactions on the website.

listeners - An array of event listeners created using the SalesforceInteractions.listener function. These events listen for customer interactions that trigger events to send through the Web SDK.

So when I add `window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (e) => { console.log("Page unload"); })` The code is executed correctly and Page unload is printed in console.

But When I use `SalesforceInteractions.listener("beforeunload", (e) => { console.log("Page unload"); })`   This peice of Code is not executed and Page Unload is not printed in console.

Is there any way where I can use `load` or `unload` event listeners using `SalesforceInteractions.listener()`? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Basically, I want how we can capture an event on page `load` and `unload` using `SalesforceInteractions.listener()`.

Thanks in Advance!